# Swift - save video from url

Tags: swift

I would like to download a movie from a URL and save to iPhone.

I use this function

```
func downloadVideo(videoUrl: URL, name: String) {
    let sampleURL = videoUrl.absoluteString
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        if let url = URL(string: sampleURL), let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: videoUrl) {
            let galleryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
            let filePath="\(galleryPath)/" + name + ".MOV"
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got this error message: "Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 16 (0x10), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug."

I added a symbolic breakpoint for UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError, but I don't understand what is wrong. What should I do to solve this problem?

Screenshot from breakpoint:

[image]

Comment: What’s the purpose of sampleURL? whats wrong with your videoURL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I got this error message: "Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 16 (0x10), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug."

This is a new warning only in the Simulator in Xcode 11. It’s unimportant. Ignore it. It happens all the time, nothing to do with your code.